# Gulp merge-stream

Tags: gulp, gulp-uglify

I am using gulp for the very first time. 
I managed doing merge streaming for css files but somehow its not working for javascript files.
Here is my code,

```
gulp.task('styles', () => {
  var commonStyles = gulp.src([
   'css/website/bootstrap.min.css',
   'css/website/font.css'
  ])

 // Concatenate and minify styles
 .pipe(minifyCss())
 .pipe(concat('style.min.css'))
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'));

 var otherStyles = gulp.src([
  'css/website/landing.css',
  'css/website/careersNew1.css'
 ])
 .pipe(minifyCss())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/styles'));

 return merge(commonStyles, otherStyles);

});

// Concatenate and minify JavaScript
gulp.task('scripts', () => {
 var commonScript = gulp.src([
  'js/scripts/jquery.min.js',
  'js/scripts/bootstrap.min.js'
 ])
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(concat('style.min.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));

var otherScript = gulp.src([
 'js/bf_scripts.js',
 'js/custom_rbox.js'
])
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'));

return merge(commonScript, otherScript);
});
```

Css output is working fine. But I am not getting any otherScript files in my dist/scripts/ folder

Answer (score 0):

You should only run `uglify()` on your custom scripts, because the jQuery and Bootstrap versions you're using are already minified/uglified, and that wastes processing time and slows down your build script.  Also, I recommend keeping libraries you download in separate folders from the custom code you write.  Keep jQuery and Bootstrap in `lib` folder, and your code in `src` folder.  You can then use wildcard globs to grab all files instead of specifying individual files.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var addsrc = require('gulp-add-src');

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  // First, uglify custom JS that you wrote
  return gulp.src('src/scripts/**/*.js')
    .pipe(uglify())

    // Now, prepend the already-minfied JS libraries you're importing and concat into style.min.js
    .pipe(addsrc.prepend('lib/scripts/**/*.js'))
    .pipe(concat('style.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
})

gulp.task('default', ['scripts'])
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use buffer before uglify;

```
var buffer = require('gulp-buffer');
.pipe(buffer())
.pipe(uglify())
```